# USPTO Patent XML, understanding the us-field-of-classification-search element

Tags: uspto, classification, file-format

I'm working with XML from the USPTO bulk download which provides weekly downloads of XML of published patent grants. I'm using [this documentation](http://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/products/PatentGrantXMLv42-Documentation.pdf) to understand the files.

I'm having trouble understanding the significance of the `us-field-of-classification-search` element (see *page 26* in the referenced documentation). It seems to be repeating fields that have already been provided, specifically, it seems to be repeating classification information provided by other elements such as those beginning on *page 11* of the aforementioned documentation.

What is this element actually providing?

Answer (score 0):

Page 83 of the referenced documentation is helpful:

> The `us-field-of-classification-search` element will always be present.
>   If the examiner did do a classification search, the element will contain one or more `classification-national` records and/or one `us-classifications-ipcr` record. 
>   If the examiner did not do a classification search, the element will contain a single `classification-national` record in which the content of the `main-classification` will be "None."

A classification search will provide national and international classes to retrieve prior art, these classes being stored as `us-classifications-ipcr` and `classification-national`.

Since the classification of an application [is checked at allowance](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s903.html#d0e114328), at least a class found during that search will be used to classify the granted application, thus at least one *value* of the element `us-field-of-classification-search` is repeated as official classe of the grant.